# How to add texture to a static object in WebGL?

Tags: javascript, webgl

Currently many of the WebGL tutorials about texture in the web are about adding texture to an animated object. I just tried to add a texture to a static object (3 sides of a cube), and it doesn't work; the object is displayed black. Here are parts of the code:

```
function initBuffers() {
VBuffer = gl.createBuffer();                            // 3D vertices
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, VBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(Verts), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

FBuffer = gl.createBuffer();                            // Facet definition
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, FBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(Faces), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

vTBuffer = gl.createBuffer();                           // Texture coordinates
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vTBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vTex), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

function handleTexture(texture) {
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture.Img);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
}

function initTextures() {
tex1 = gl.createTexture();
tex1.Img = new Image();
tex1.Img.onload = function() { handleTexture(tex1); }
tex1.Img.src = texImgs[0];                            // "cubetexture.png"
}

function drawScene() {
    ...  

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, VBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertexPositionAttribute, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vTBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(texCoordAttribute, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex1);
gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uSampler"), 0);

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, FBuffer);
setMatrixUniforms();
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, nVF, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
}
```

And these functions are called at the loading of the page as follows:

```
...
initBuffers();
initTextures();
drawScene();
```

But what I get is only a black object. Any suggestion how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you load and handle texture (aka prepare it for use), then once more call `drawScene()` so the texture could be picked.

```
function handleTexture(texture) {
    // code....
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);

    drawScene();
}
```

Comment: The problem is "tex1.Img.src = texImgs[0];" fetches the texture data asynchronously, so the first (and only) drawScene() gets called before the texture loading is finished. You need to reorganize the code to call drawScene() once the texture is fully ready. Just like the example provided by @AbstractAlgorithm .

Comment: Thanks, guys! I just know that this texture data fetching is done asynchronously.